# Login working in Splash API but not when SplashRequest is used

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

Relatively new to Splash. I'm trying to scrape a website which needs a login. I started off with the Splash API for which I was able to login perfectly. However, when I put my code in a scrapy spider script, using SplashRequest, it's  not able to login.

```
import scrapy  
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class Payer1Spider(scrapy.Spider):  
    name = "payer1"  
    start_url = "https://provider.wellcare.com/provider/claims/search"  
    lua_script = """  
    function main(splash,args)  
        assert(splash:go(args.url))  
        splash:wait(0.5)  

    local search_input = splash:select('#Username')  
    search_input:send_text('')  

    local search_input = splash:select('#Password')
    search_input:send_text('')

    assert(splash:wait(0.5))
    local login_button = splash:select('#btnSubmit')
    login_button:mouse_click()

    assert(splash:wait(7))
    return{splash:html()}
end
"""

def start_requests(self):
    yield SplashRequest(self.start_url, self.parse_result,args={'lua_source': self.lua_script},)

def parse_result(self, response):
    yield {'doc_title' : response.text}
```

The output HTML is the login page and not the one after logging in.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `endpoint='execute'` to your SplashRequest to execute the lua-script:

```
yield SplashRequest(self.start_url, self.parse_result, args={'lua_source': self.lua_script}, endpoint='execute')
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't need splash to login to the site indeed. You can try next:

Get `https://provider.wellcare.com` and then..

```
# Get request verification token..
token = response.css('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]::attr(value)').get()

# Forge post request payload...
data = [
  ('__RequestVerificationToken', token),
  ('Username', 'user'),
  ('Password', 'pass'),
  ('ReturnUrl', '/provider/claims/search'),
]

#Make dict from list of tuples
formdata=dict(data)

# And then execute request
scrapy.FormRequest(
   url='https://provider.wellcare.com/api/sitecore/Login', 
   formdata=formdata
)
```

Not completely sure if all of this will work. But you can try.

Comment: I'm able to do it using FormRequest, I just wanted to know if something was going wrong with the SplashRequest, as it works fine in the API.